# Validation on server display to user or just send error 400

Tags: c#

I need to do server validation in c# after I have done client validation in Angular.
I read many posts in stackoverflow on this matter. But didn't find an answer.
Should I send error such as 400 when validation on the server fails or should I display to user the errors and which fields should be fixed.
Thanks.

Comment: So, did it help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but what I wanted to know is whether when validating in server I should send the error back to user and show where input should be fixed or assume that if there's wrong input then it's malicious user and send some error such as 400

Comment: And what I'm saying is, always return `200`, but also the `ResponseBase<>` object. Then, use this object to perform stuff is JS: whether was success or not, print the errors or Message, use the Output etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is a generic question, with possibly a lot of resources on the internet, I will still give you a suggestion:

Generally, you could have a generic object to use for resposes, e.x:

```
public class ResponseBase<T>
{
    public bool IsSuccess => (Errors is null || !Errors.Any());
    public IList<string> Errors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public T Output { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use this for API responses.
`T` is the actual object you are performing operation(s) on, for e.x: `ResponseBase<CustomerDto>`